# Ensuring tkinter buttons only work in a certain order

Tags: python, tkinter, button, poker

I have another question about some poker playing code I am writing in Python tkinter. I have a number of buttons in my GUI, but some should not be pressed before others, and some should only be pressed a certain maximum number of times. I can create global 'click count' variables. But I was given to understand that global should be used sparingly. Is there another way of making buttons only work if certain conditions are met?
Here is some slimmed down code:

```
from tkinter import *

x = Tk()
x.state('zoomed')

def lay():
    card1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2)
    card2.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2)

def bet():
    print('BET should only be pressed after LAY CARDS, and max twice')

card1 = Label(x, text='card1')
card2 = Label(x, text='card2')

Button(x, text='LAY CARDS', command=lay).place(relx=0.2, rely=0.5)
Button(x, text='BET', command=bet).place(relx=0.4, rely=0.5)

x.mainloop()
```

On a more general note, I started writing this code simply as a challenge, and the GUI is not the most important part. However, having started, I would like to get it in full working order. I find that while there are abundant resources on Python, there is a lack of helpful info on Tkinter, especially for the kind of interactive code I would like to create (by 'interactive' I mean code where there are several buttons each producing a different sequence of actions that should be done in a certain order). Does anyone know of a good book on using Tkinter written in very beginner-friendly terms?

Answer (score 0):

The states of the buttons can be set to normal / disabled by other button clicks.
The count variable can be placed in a closure to let it be retained and updated
but not be global to the applcation.

An alternative would be to create a class for the counter with the command function as a method using object orientated programming.

The bet button is disabled until lay is clicked.  The lay function disables lay and enables bet.  The bet function disables bet after two clicks.

```
import tkinter as tk

x = tk.Tk()
x.state('zoomed')

def lay():
    card1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2)
    card2.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2)
    # Set bet_button to NORMAL after lay is clicked
    bet_button.config( state = tk.NORMAL )
    lay_button.config( state = tk.DISABLED ) # lay DISABLED

def make_bet():
    # Returns a function making a closure.  
    # count can be 'seen' by bet but is not global.
    count = 0
    
    def bet():
        nonlocal count
        count += 1
        print( 'BET pressed {} times.'.format(count) )
        if count > 1:
            bet_button.config( state = tk.DISABLED )

    return bet

card1 = tk.Label(x, text='card1')
card2 = tk.Label(x, text='card2')

lay_button = tk.Button(x, text='LAY CARDS', command=lay)
lay_button.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.5)

bet_button = tk.Button(x, text='BET', command=make_bet(), state = tk.DISABLED)
# make_bet requires the brackets as it returns the appropriate function
bet_button.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.5)

x.mainloop()
```